# Segfault while using memcmp

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want to compare 2 unsigned bytes in hex. This is what I tried:

```
if (memcmp (msgType ,  0x00003336, 2 ) == 0){}
```

This is what gcc prints for  msgType :

```
(gdb) x msgType
0x7fffffffbb84: 0x00003336
```

I'm getting segfault. How can I fix it?

## EDIT:

I tried :

```
const unsigned char broadcast[2] = {0x33, 0x36};
```

But gdb shows:

```
(gdb) x broadcast
0x401e28 <broadcast>:   0x62723633
```

I need: `0x00003336`

Comment: What is the address `0x00003336` supposed to be? Read e.g. [this `memcmp` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp).

Comment: @JKB (after fixing the typo -- extra 'f') That will avoid the segfault while also not functioning according to what the OP expects.

Comment: @MaMu it's `broadcast` pointing mamory not `messageType`. So try `if(memcmp(msgType, broadcast, sizeof broadcast) == 0)`

Comment: you'd want to do `x/2b broadcast` in gdb, or `x/h broadcast` Or `p/x broadcast`. With `x` you have to tell gdb the length and type you want to print. with `p` it figures out the data type.

Comment: What is the type of `msgType`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to write simply `if (msgType == 0x00003336)` or somethign similar depending on the type of msgType. BTW what exactly is the type of msgType ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two arguments to `memcmp()` are *pointers* to the memory blocks to compare. [See the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp), the prototype is:

```
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

You are using the absolute address 0x00003336 as the value of `s2`, which seems very wrong; that's not a valid address in the general case.

To fix this, you must create a memory area that holds the value you want to compare against, and pass a pointer to that as the second argument. Try:

```
const uint8_t data[] = { 0x36, 0x33 };

if(memcmp(msgType, data, sizeof data) == 0)
{
}
```

Note that the bytes are swapped in the above, on the assumption that you're on a little-endian system.

Comment: it doesn't give me 0.

Comment: @MaMu I had forgotten to swap the two bytes. You should really include the type of `msgType` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pointer as second argument, you can't just pass an hex value in there

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/

Something that might work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    unsigned char msgType[2] = {0x33, 0x36};
    unsigned char your_value[2] = {0x33, 0x36};

    // Make sure your_value is the same size of msgType
    if (memcmp (msgType ,  your_value, sizeof(msgType)/sizeof(unsigned char) ) == 0){
        printf("Yes, memory is equal at that address!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/EQH6py

Answer (score 0):

If your process does not own the memory at `0x00003336` then you will get *undefined behaviour*: manifested, in this particular instance, as a segfault.

The normal thing to do here is to pass a pointer to a variable that you have instantiated yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Both of `memcmp()`'s first two arguments must be pointers to memory. You seem to be passing in a value you want to compare against, rather than a pointer to that value.

Instead, try this:

```
unsigned short expectedValue = 0x3336;
if (memcmp (msgType, &expectedValue, 2) == 0){}
```

Comment: On a little endian host, you'd have to do `unsigned short expectedValue = 0x3633;` though

Comment: @nos if I specified as an array of chars then you would be right, but I specified as an unsigned short; endianness will order the bytes correctly.

Comment: Anyway, it depends on what type `msgType` is. If it's a short too, then the comparison here is probably ok (but one could just have done `msgType == expectedValue;`). If it's a 2 byte array, someone have to consider endianess somewhere.

Comment: The op's edit does suggest a 2 byte array, but looking at his output of "x address" one gets different results for the unspecified type msgType and for the char array broadcast. The output of x msgType is consistent with a unsigned long of 0x????3336, in this case 00's for the MSW, stored in memory as 36 33 00 00.